# Remove Excel workbook onSelectionChange event

Tags: excel, typescript, office-js, office-addins, exceljs

I am working on a Excel Web Add-In using Office.js. I added onSelectionChange event for a workbook and later trying to remove it, but this event still works. Here you can find an example that I created with ScriptLab, that shows that event can not be removed:
https://gist.github.com/shss1985/afd1c00484acfec33740cdbcda3f78b5

Is there a way to remove it correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the handler you have to use the same RequestContext as was used to add it. For details about how you do this, see [Remove an event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events#remove-an-event-handler).

Comment: No Code :( An line of code is worth 1k words.

Comment: hey Rick, don't think I don't appreciate all your answers, I see you everywhere, just being unbiased! I actually figured out the issue I am having w/ removing events (its due to the `same context` clause). I posted a similar question on how to check for events if you have a moment --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71904238/check-for-existing-event-handlers-on-worksheet-office-js-excel

Answer (score -1):

Removing them looks like this --> But, must be called in the same `context` so my issue is really that I need to be able to check if they are already registered, as this `remove` doesn't remove previously setup `event handlers` when my page refreshes and gets new `context`

Note: the `var` lines actually register the event, so you can comment out the remove to test.

```
var var_onActivated = ws.onActivated.add(Client_WOs_Do_onActivated);
var var_onDeactivated = ws.onDeactivated.add(Client_WOs_onDeactivated);

await var_onActivated.remove();
await var_onDeactivated.remove();
```