# Check for Existing Event Handlers on Worksheet - Office JS - Excel

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

I'm trying to register event handlers for worksheets in my add-in and it works, but each time they re-load the taskpane it's re-adding the handlers and they are firing multiple times.

How can I check if there is already an event handler registered for worksheet events like `onActived`? I've debated/tested a bit w/ `local/session storage` but thats not ideal and I'd prefer to actually check the worksheet.

Is there a way?

I'm working on Excel on Windows.

Update: This may be related to how I load taskpanes.

I have a single taskpane that is generic and then I load specific taskpanes into a Div element on the main/generic taskpane using  `$(document).ready(function () { $('#' + ParentElm).load(HTMLFileStr) });`

I think I can live w/ `sessionStorage` as I'm literally trying to track a variable per session, it's appropriate, but I'd still prefer to check/know how to/if possible to check worksheet for events registered if I could vs using storage/flags.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to store info in the document, you could try CustomProperty or CustomXmlPart.

Comment: This article, [Work with Events using Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events), says "An event handler is created when an add-in registers the event handler. It is destroyed when the add-in unregisters the event handler or when the add-in is refreshed, reloaded, or closed." So, I think what you are describing shouldn't be happening or am I missing something?

Comment: @RickKirkham My Add-In uses a probably non standard way which might be related, but I didn't include. I have one add-in that uses only `ExecuteFunction` in the `manifest` and that loads specific `html` files into `div` on the main `index.htlm`. This allows "multiple taskpanes" but only technically a "single taskpane". But each time my function loads the taskpane, its re-adding the event.

Comment: My guess is I can't check for `events registered` on the `worksheet`?