# Remove all event handlers from worbook/worksheet/table

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I'm using ScriptLab to play with event handlers. Every time I run a script, a new event handler is registered.
I know how to [remove one event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events#remove-an-event-handler), but everytime the code execution is refreshed, it is not possible anymore to delete the event handler registered in the last execution, so they get stacked and execute with the new code.

I'd like to know if it is possible to remove all event handlers from a worksheet, table, workbook, etc.

Maybe a way to access a collection of registered event handlers and allow to delete them, the same way we can do with JavaScript.

---

EDIT: code for context

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));
$("#remove").click(() => tryCatch(remove));

let eventResult;

async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    eventResult = worksheet.onSelectionChanged.add(handleSelectionChange);

    await context.sync();
    console.log("Event handler successfully registered for onSelectionChanged event in the worksheet.");
  });
}

async function handleSelectionChange(event) {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    await context.sync();
    console.log("Address of current selection: " + event.address);
  });
}

async function remove() {
  await Excel.run(eventResult.context, async (context) => {
    eventResult.remove();
    await context.sync();

    eventResult = null;
    console.log("Event handler successfully removed.");
  });
}
/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

See that it is easy to remove a handler if you store it in a variable (`eventResult`). But as soon as I make any change to the ScriptLab code pane, every variable is resetted, but the event is still active in the worksheet.

I'd like a way to remove the event(s) even if the code goes out of context and variables lose state.

Comment: A code sample would be a big plus.

Comment: And can you share more detail about "everytime the code execution is refreshed" action? Thanks very much!

Comment: I know I had this exact issue. I resorted to using sessionstorage, but even that isn't ideal. I was directed to look at using `customXML` document properties to store a boolean value of 'registered'.

Comment: See --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71904238/check-for-existing-event-handlers-on-worksheet-office-js-excel

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, thanks that might be helpful. So, what did you do? Are you using session storage to store the handlers? Did it work? Did you serialize it? I wonder if it is possible to serialize because of properties loops.

Comment: You should post some code. Im currently using session storage but the issue is multiple workbook open simultaneously doesn't work well. I tested and got customxml working, just need to write the code so to speak.

Comment: Added code to provide more context.